# obtaining the first link for a search result with the `rvest` package in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

NOTE: this question does not violate Google's Terms of Service. The use case and purposes are compliant and within the ToS.

The object `url` is an atomic character vector that stores a URL:

`url <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=Kendrick+Lamar+aoty"`

I need to obtain the first non-ad link that Google's search results return and store it as the object `link`. Here's what I do now:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=Kendrick+Lamar+aoty"

search_page <- read_html(url)

first_link <- search_page %>%
  html_nodes(".g:not(.g .adsbygoogle)") %>%
  html_node("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  URLdecode()
```

I get the following error:

`Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : Expected ')', got .`

The issue looks like my call to `html_nodes()` function. I have modified the CSS classifier in several ways but have not been successful in resolving the error. The result I'm expecting to store in the `first_link` object based on the example above is:

`https://www.albumoftheyear.org/artist/1881-kendrick-lamar/`

What am I doing wrong with the `html_nodes()` function (or something else that I'm missing if I want to get the desired output as shown above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solution good for you?

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=Kendrick+Lamar+aoty"
search_page <- read_html(url)

links <- search_page |> 
  html_elements("a") |> 
  html_attr("href") 
  
i <- stringr::str_detect(links, "url\\?q\\=")
out <- stringr::str_extract(links[i], "https.*?(?=\\&)")

out
```

Comment: This does - `out` returns a ton of links, but when I modify the call to `stringr::str_extract(links[i], "https.*?(?=\\&)")[1]` I get the first. Thanks!